# Drools Business Central Workbench WAR for JBoss EAP7

Tags: drools, jboss7.x

The current **Drools** documentation (7.47.0) says on chapter 14 that one should use the WAR from the **Business Central Workbench** distribution corresponding to the application server in use and explicitly refers to  Wildfly  and JBoss EAP 7 as available options.

However,  only the Wildfly WAR of Business Central 7.47.0 is available from the official Drools download page and from the Maven repository.

Can anyone please point me **how to obtain  the WAR for JBoss EAP 7**? Is it otherwise possible to easily build it directly from source?

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly is upstream project and JBoss EAP is downstream / productized one, fully supported by Red Hat. It's based on WildFly though.
The same relationship exists between Drools and Red Hat Decision Manager (RHDM).

I would recommend to stick with Drools and Wildfly unless you are Red Hat paying customer.
If you are paying customer, then you should use RHDM+EAP. It's possible to use RHDM+EAP for development purposes for free though:
https://developers.redhat.com/products/red-hat-decision-manager/hello-world#fndtn-macos